# CNN Gives Same Loss And Accuracy

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN using pytorch. When I use 3 or fewer consecutive layers, it appears to work correctly, with the loss decreasing and the accuracy increasing. However, when I have 4 or more conv2d layers in a row, the loss and accuracy remain constant (accuracy=0.0961). Occasionally, the 4+ layer models work, but if I try training them again, they have the aforementioned problem. I am testing using the MNIST dataset.

My code is below:

```
from pathlib import Path
import requests
import pickle
import gzip
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

DATA_PATH = Path("data")
PATH = DATA_PATH / "mnist"

PATH.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

URL = "http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/"
FILENAME = "mnist.pkl.gz"

if not (PATH / FILENAME).exists():
    content = requests.get(URL + FILENAME).content
    (PATH / FILENAME).open("wb").write(content)


with gzip.open((PATH / FILENAME).as_posix(), "rb") as f:
        ((x_train, y_train), (x_valid, y_valid), _) = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin-1")


x_train = torch.tensor(x_train)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train).unsqueeze(1)

x_valid = torch.tensor(x_valid)
y_valid = torch.tensor(y_valid).unsqueeze(1)


train_ds = TensorDataset(x_train, y_train)
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

valid_ds = TensorDataset(x_valid, y_valid)
valid_dl = DataLoader(valid_ds, batch_size=64)


class Lambda(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.func(x)

def preprocess(x):
  return x.view(-1, 1, 28, 28)


model = nn.Sequential(
    Lambda(preprocess),
    nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=2, padding_mode='zeros'),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=2, padding_mode='zeros'),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=2, padding_mode='zeros'),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=2, padding_mode='zeros'),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((10, 1)),
    Lambda(lambda x: x.squeeze(1)),
    nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)


def loss_batch(model, loss_func, xb, yb, opt=None):
  pred = model(xb)
  loss = loss_func(pred, yb)

  if opt is not None:
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    opt.zero_grad()
    return loss.item(), len(xb)
  else:
    label = torch.argmax(pred, dim=1)
    correct = (label == yb).float().sum()
    accuracy = correct/len(xb)
    return loss.item(), len(xb), accuracy


def fit(epochs, model, loss_func, opt, train_dl, valid_dl):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    losses = []
    nums = []
    for xb, yb in train_dl:
      loss, num = loss_batch(model, loss_func, xb, yb, opt)
      losses.append(loss)
      nums.append(num)
    train_loss = np.sum(np.multiply(losses, nums)) / np.sum(nums)


    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
      losses = []
      nums = []
      accuracies = []
      for xb, yb in valid_dl:
        loss, num, accuracy = loss_batch(model, loss_func, xb, yb)
        losses.append(loss)
        nums.append(num)
        accuracies.append(accuracy)
      val_loss = np.sum(np.multiply(losses, nums)) / np.sum(nums)
      val_acc = np.sum(np.multiply(accuracies, nums)) / np.sum(nums)


      print("Epoch ", epoch+1, ": ", train_loss, val_loss, val_acc)


opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
fit(20, model, F.cross_entropy, opt, train_dl, valid_dl)
```

Comment: Hey! Can you edit your post so that the question is more clear? Do you want to know why adding more layers will decrease the accuracy?